# Why do parts of my windows blank out in KDE?

Tags: kde5, kwin

My computer: Lenovo ThinkPad E15 Gen 2 with Intel Corporation TigerLake GT2 [Iris Xe Graphics] (rev 01) graphics controller, running Debian 11 and KDE plasmashell 5.20.5.

I have an odd problem: several windowed applications (konsole, firefox and others) 'blink' from time to time; in konsole if seems to be connected with text being printed - see the two pictures below. Sometimes a line 'disappears' after a line of text is printed by ping, then it comes back when the next line is printed. On other occasions it is a whole area of text, and ofcourse, it is intermittent. It doesn't seem to affect all programs, but I have certainly seen it in konsole and firefox. Any idea how to address this?

[image: A line blanks out] [image: And then it is back]

Comment: Which backend ? X11 or Wayland ? Also does disabling compositing (via system-settings) help ?

Comment: I'm using X11. Not quite sure if I turned off compositing: System Settings -> Display and Monitor -> Compositor -> uncheck 'Enable compositor on startup' -> Apply. This doesn't change things.

Comment: Should restart kde after that change.

Comment: I've restarted KDE with `systemctl restart sddm`, and it may have fixed it, but it is too early to be sure.

Comment: @MC68020 It seems to have worked - thank you! If you write it up as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Versions of kwin (KDE-Plasma screen compositor) < 5.21 offer a suboptimal way to [sync on VBlank](https://invent.kde.org/plasma/kwin/-/merge_requests/507) this leading to screen tearing and miscellaneous other inconveniences depending on the graphical adaptor when compositor is enabled.

KDE-Plasma current being 5.25 to date, the very best advice is to upgrade your 5.20.5 to whatever >= 5.21 your distribution can offer.

If impossible for whatever reason then a first possible workaround consists in forcing the video adaptor so sync on VBlank (possible with nvidia-settings for nvidia adaptors, I cannot tell for others and set KDE-Plasma sync to VBlank mode to NEVER (via kde-systemsettings > Display)

If the above trick still does not provide satisfactory results then the very last solution to get definitely rid of the problem consists in : **Disabling compositing entirely.**